# Else-if statement doesn't seem to be executed

Tags: ios, objective-c, if-statement

I have an `if` statement which checks if a draggable `imageView` intersects with another `imageView` - which keeps count of the amount of items dragged to it and changes an image. I also have an `else-if` statement to see if 2 `imageViews` have intersected with the counter `imageView`. The first `if` statement works fine, but when I go to drag another one on to it nothing happens. The image doesn't change. I tried to do it the following way but it doesn't seem to work.

Anyone know why and if there is a better way to do it?

My code:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{

    for (UIImageView *letter in letterA)
    {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame ,answerA.frame))
        {
            UIImage *Pic1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number1"];
            [correctCounterA setImage:Pic1];
            letter.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            letter.hidden=YES;

        }
        else if(CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame ,answerA.frame) && CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame, answerA.frame))
        {
            UIImage *Pic2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number2"];
            [correctCounterA setImage:Pic2];
            letter.userInteractionEnabled=NO;
            letter.hidden=YES;
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: X && Y is even more restrictive than X. There is no case where `!X && X && Y`. Rethinking your boolean logic may be the key here.

Comment: Escpecially since it is actually `X && X`...

Comment: how would i go about it then? letter is from array of `UIImageViews`. I was trying to access a random one each time but with no luck

Comment: you if-else brach look like this: `if (A) { ... } else if (A && A) { ... } `. what is that? where is the reasonable logic? what do you what to achieve here?

Comment: I have 4 of A. They are in an array and was hoping every time i call it it will use any of them that i click on.

Comment: What exactly do you want to do?  Your current logic is:  "If `letter` intersects `answerA`, do some stuff.  __Otherwise__, if `letter` intersects `answerA` __and__ `letter` intersects `answerA`, do some other stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like this is what you're after:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int intersectionCount = 0;
    for (UIImageView *letter in letterA) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame ,answerA.frame)) {
            letter.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            letter.hidden = YES;
            intersectionCount++;
        }
    }

    if (intersectionCount == 1) {
        UIImage *Pic1 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number1"];
        [correctCounterA setImage:Pic1];
    }

    else if (intersectionCount == 2) {
        UIImage *Pic2 = [UIImage imageNamed:@"number2"];
        [correctCounterA setImage:Pic2];
    }
}
```

Or perhaps more generally:

```
- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    int intersectionCount = 0;
    for (UIImageView *letter in letterA) {
        if (CGRectIntersectsRect(letter.frame ,answerA.frame)) {
            letter.userInteractionEnabled = NO;
            letter.hidden = YES;
            intersectionCount++;
        }
    }

    if (intersectionCount == 0) {
        [correctCounterA setImage:nil];
    }

    else {
        NSString *imageName = [NSString
            stringWithFormat:@"number%d", intersectionCount];
        UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:imageName];
        [correctCounterA setImage:image];
    }
}
```

Comment: This is kinda of working but for some reason when i try to add any off the `imageViews` it doesnt work. It takes the specific ones and not random. Is it because i use `IBOutletCollection` ? Is There a way to make it random so it wont matter in which order i drag them?

Comment: It actually follows a pattern. The first dragged will change to number1, the second will do nothing, the third will change to number2 and the fourth one will change it back to number1, any ideas why this is the case?

Answer (score 1):

your second condition covers just a subset of the first, so it's either true already in the first case or will never be ...

Your current question is:
If letter intersects answer do something.
If letter does not intersect answer then if letter intersects answer and letter intersects answer do something else.

I'm missing some alternative here ...

Comment: I tried `+, &&` and some other operators but none seem to work, is there a way to do it differently?

Comment: Sure, depends on what you want to achieve. Currently your else case is a special case of the if statement - you could put it inside the first if, if that's what you want ...

Comment: Please try to explain what you want to achieve, so I can point you in the right direction

Comment: I have 4 imageViews that are in an array. I want to be able to drag them on another imageView that counts how many was dragged. Say if I drag 1 then it changes its image to number 1 and if i drag more then it will change to the number acordingly. Does this help? Also it should not matter in which order they are dragged in

Answer (score 0):

If the goal is to implement draggable views and detect intersections then I would approach the problem like this:

```
@interface ViewController()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewOne;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewTwo;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewThree;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *imageViewFour;    
@property (nonatomic) BOOL hasView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *imageViewCollection;
@property (strong, nonatomic) UIImageView *viewToDrag;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIImageView *destinationView;
@property (nonatomic) NSUInteger destinationViewCounter;
@property (nonatomic) CGPoint originalLocation;
@end


- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.imageViewCollection = @[_imageViewOne, _imageViewTwo, _imageViewThree, _imageViewFour];
    self.view.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
}

- (void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
    CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    for(UIImageView *view in _imageViewCollection) {
        if(CGRectContainsPoint(view.frame, touchLocation)) {
            self.originalLocation = view.center;
            self.viewToDrag = view;
            self.hasView = YES;
        }
    }
}

- (void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(self.hasView) {
        UITouch *touch = [[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint touchLocation = [touch locationInView:self.view];
        self.viewToDrag.center = touchLocation;
        [self.view bringSubviewToFront: self.viewToDrag];
    }
}

- (void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    if(CGRectIntersectsRect(self.destinationView.frame, self.viewToDrag.frame)) {
        NSUInteger tagNumber = self.viewToDrag.tag;
        [self removeImageForTagNumber:tagNumber];   //to remove imageViews after dragged
        self.viewToDrag.center = self.originalLocation;
        self.destinationViewCounter++;
        self.viewToDrag = nil;
        if(self.destinationViewCounter > 4) {
            self.destinationViewCounter = 0; //if we're out of range reset the counter
        }
        self.destinationView.image = [self imageForNumber:self.destinationViewCounter];   //convenience method to grab the correct image (correlating to the counter)
    }  
    self.viewToDrag.center = self.originalLocation; //snap the imageView back into place
    self.hasView = NO;
}

- (void)removeImageForTagNumber:(NSUInteger)number {
    switch (number) {
        case 1:
            [_imageViewOne removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        case 2:
            [_imageViewTwo removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        case 3:
            [_imageViewThree removeFromSuperview];
            break;
        case 4:
            [_imageViewFour removeFromSuperview];
        default:
            return;
    }
}
```

I have also created an example project for you [here](https://github.com/BenJamminnn/DraggableViews)

Comment: This works great but do you know how to make the `imageView`disappear after its dragged correctly?

Comment: Yes. There are multiple ways to do this but this is the simplest that comes to mind:
1) set tag numbers for your image views either in storyboard or programmatically
2) now `viewToDrag` will be able to tell us exactly which `imageView` we would need to remove if it reaches the `destinationView`
3) Implement a simple convenience method to take in a number and remove the corresponding `imageView`

Comment: how do i set tag numbers?

Comment: Either in storyboard: select the imageview > Attributes > tag
or setting it programmatically, `_imageView.tag = 1`